# Solutions of inhomogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra

let Ax = b be a linear system when $A \in M_{m,n}(F), \ b\in F^m$

if $x_1, x_2$ are solutions of the system then $\forall c \in F,\ cx_1 +(1-c)x_2$ is also a solution of the system.

I think the statement is incorrect because $Ax = b$ is not a linear sub-space which means that it's not closed under addition. Can someone confirm my statement or fix me if i'm wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try applying $A$ to $cx_1 + (1-c)x_2$ and using linearity. What is the result?

Comment: @TrevorNorton c * Ax_1 + (1-c) * Ax_2

Comment: That's right. Now we know $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions to the linear system. So $Ax_1=b$ and $Ax_2 = b$. So $c Ax_1 + (1-c)Ax_2 = cb + (1-c)b = b.$

Answer (score 0):

Linearity quickly destroys this.

Convex combinations are just special linear combinations. What happens if we multiply this "solution" by $A$? Well,

\begin{align*}
Ax &= A(cx_1 + (1-c)x_2) \\
&= Acx_1 + A(1-c)x_2 \\
&= cb + (1-c)b \\
&= b
\end{align*}

as required.